# C++ Paper Pencil Algorithm Addition - Problem adding numbers due to memory loss

Tags: c++

I have an issue with my algorithm where as it doesn't work with huge numbers please someone help me fix my algorithm.

**Attempt 1**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void reverse(int arr[], int n) {
    reverse(arr, arr + n);
}

long long int PaperPencilAlgorithm(string num1, string num2)
{
    long long int result = 0;
    long long int lennum1 = num1.length();
    long long int lennum2 = num2.length();
    long long int result2 = 0;

        int *arrnum1 = new int[lennum1];
        int *arrnum2 = new int[lennum2];
        for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum1; x++)
        {
            arrnum1[x] = num1[x] - 48;                  
        }
        int x = 0;
        for (long long int y = lennum1 - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {   
            result = result + (arrnum1[x] * pow(10, y));
            x++;
        }

        for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum2; x++)
        {
            arrnum2[x] = num2[x] - 48;
        }
        x = 0;
        for (long long int y = lennum2 - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            result2 = result2 + (arrnum2[x] * pow(10, y));
            x++;
        }
        return result+result2;
    }

int main()
{
    cout << "Paper and Pencil Algorithm Addition" << endl;
    string num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter num 1: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter num 2: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "Addition of two numbers is : " << PaperPencilAlgorithm(num1, num2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Want to add 2 more numbers? (Y/n)" << endl;
    char c;
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 'Y')
    {
        system("CLS");
        main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is due to the error of conversion __int64 to unsigned int
I am new to C++ please can someone help me out to make my program working 100%

**Warning messages from IDE**

```
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'double' to '__int64', possible loss of data   Q1.cpp  37  
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'double' to '__int64', possible loss of data   Q1.cpp  26  
Warning C4244   'argument': conversion from '__int64' to 'const unsigned int', possible loss of data    Q1.cpp  32  
Warning C4244   'argument': conversion from '__int64' to 'const unsigned int', possible loss of data    Q1.cpp  21  
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from '__int64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data  Q1.cpp  18  
Warning C4244   'initializing': conversion from '__int64' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data  Q1.cpp  17
```

Comment: That's c++ for 'ya.

Comment: P.s.: `main();` <-- this won't work(It *could*, but it shouldn't)

Comment: @NikitaDemodov works in Visual Studio in a .exe format.

Comment: It's actually *forbidden* to call [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) by yourself. It leads to *undefined behavior*. If you need a loop, use an actual loop.

Comment: @Ashlin Yes, but this makes it less portable. You using `system` already makes it unportable but this makes it so that it isn't even standards compliant.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i will try it out now and let you know the outcome.

Comment: And please don't post images of text. If you get build errors, they will be available as text, so please [edit] your question and include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste (as text) of the build output.

Comment: Despite the function's name, you have not implemented a paper-and-pencil algorithm (the kind where you perform addition digit by digit, and can add arbitrarily long sequences of digits). You are just converting the whole string to an integer - which of course won't work with a long enough string. The whole point of doing it pencil-and-paper way is to be able to handle large numbers that won't fit in a CPU register.

Comment: @NikitaDemodov only need it to run in Windows.

Comment: @AshlinGovindasamy This doesn't change anything. Even on Windows, with the next Visual Studio or Windows update this might just stop working and you won't know. It's like dividing by (int)0.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik do you have a solution for me?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks will change it now, I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The solution for you is to actually implement the [paper-and-pencil algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_arithmetic#Addition_algorithm) as the problem statement demands; what you have now is nowhere close. If you are asking "would you write the code for me", then no, I would not.

Comment: @AshlinGovindasamy `using namespace std; void reverse(int arr[], int n) { reverse(arr, arr + n);}` -- This is a classic case of why `using namespace std;` is not recommended.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I never ended up using that function but it works. i get what you saying thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @AshlinGovindasamy -- There is no need for floating point function calls such as `pow` in an integer, digit-by-digit algorithm.  Second, you are really overthinking this whole assignment.  You're supposed to align the two numbers (stick leading zeros if the numbers aren't the same length).  Then add up a column of numbers, stick the mod 10 of the result in the answer column, and if there is a carry, record that and go to the next column.  Absolutely no different than what you were taught in grade school.  In grade school, did you use powers to add up a column of numbers?  I don't think so.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks will redo the algorithm, thanks for your input. Got an idea of what to do now.

Comment: Just some hints you might want to consider: 1. If you add two numbers, there might remain a carry if you have used all digits of the larger of the two numbers. So the result *might* have one more digit than the larger number. So reserve sufficent space for: `std::max(lennum1, lennum2)`. 2. Your string will contain characters, unfortunately the characters for ciphers are not mapped to 0, 1, ..., but (ASCII provided, there are other incompatible encodings like infamous EBCDIC) to 48, 49, ... – the safe way to get the digit value is `num[index] - '0'`.

Comment: 3. Start at both strings from the very end, add the two digits at corresponding indices *and* the carry (the latter initially 0), result's current digit is `sum % 10`, new carry is `sum / 10`. 4. You need special handling for the case one of the strings has no more digits left.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the advice. Once im done i will put the code up.

Comment: @ADG Just about sufficient memory: Must be, of course, `std::max(...) + 1`. Strange how I could miss that +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt 2 Solution**
*Memory Error still occurs partially working*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void reverse(int arr[], int n) {
    std::reverse(arr, arr + n);
}

void PaperPencilAlgorithm(string num1, string num2)
{
    long long int lennum1 = num1.length();
    long long int lennum2 = num2.length();

        int *arrnum1 = new int[lennum1];
        int *arrnum2 = new int[lennum2];

        if (lennum1 > lennum2)
        {
            for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum1; x++)
            {
                arrnum1[x] = num1[x] - 48;
                arrnum2[x] = 0;
            }
            for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum2; x++)
            {
                arrnum2[x] = num2[x] - 48;
            }

            reverse(arrnum1, lennum1);
            reverse(arrnum2, lennum2);
            int remain = 0;
            int* result = new int[lennum1];
            for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum1; x++)
            {
                if (arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x] >= 10)
                {
                    string no = to_string(arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x]);
                    result[x] = remain + no[1] - 48;
                    remain = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[x] = arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x] + remain;
                    remain = 0;
                }
            }
            reverse(result, lennum1);
            cout << "Addtion Solution is:" << " ";
            if (remain == 1)
            {
                cout << 1;
                for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum1; x++)
                {
                    cout << result[x] << "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum1; x++)
                {
                    cout << result[x] << "";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum2; x++)
            {
                arrnum2[x] = num2[x] - 48;
                arrnum1[x] = 0;
            }
            for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum1; x++)
            {
                arrnum1[x] = num1[x] - 48;
            }

            reverse(arrnum1, lennum1);
            reverse(arrnum2, lennum2);
            int remain = 0;
            int* result = new int[lennum2];
            for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum2; x++)
            {
                if (arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x] >= 10)
                {
                    string no = to_string(arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x]);
                    result[x] = remain + no[1] - 48;
                    remain = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    result[x] = arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x] + remain;
                    remain = 0;
                }
            }
            reverse(result, lennum2);
            cout << "Addtion Solution is:" << " ";
            if (remain == 1)
            {
                cout << 1;
                for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum2; x++)
                {
                    cout << result[x] << "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (long long int x = 0; x < lennum2; x++)
                {
                    cout << result[x] << "";
                }
            }
            cout << endl;




        }
    
    }

void Display()
{
    cout << "Paper and Pencil Algorithm Addition" << endl;
    string num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter num 1: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter num 2: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    PaperPencilAlgorithm(num1, num2);
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Want to add 2 more numbers? (Y/n)" << endl;
    char c;
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 'Y')
    {
        system("CLS");
        Display();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution leaks memory.  Second, I don't see where the sum, mod 10, and carry are performed.  Honestly, two add big integers represented as strings take up half the code you've written.

Comment: `if (lennum1 > lennum2)` -- Look at your code carefully.  You have an entire repetition of the same code.  If one number is longer in length than the other number, just make whatever the shorter number is the same length as the longer number.   Once you do that, it doesn't matter originally what number was longer than the other.

Comment: Also: `if (arrnum1[x] + arrnum2[x] >= 10)` -- There is no need for this `if` statement.  You were told to simply add the two digits, and add the carry to produce a "sub" sum.  Then **automatically**, the digit to place in the answer is the mod 10 of that sum, and the carry is that sum divided by 10.  There are no `if` statements to deal with.  Do you know what the modulus does?  [Here is an example of what you should have at least attempted](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e33ca46c6753941).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks <3 for the solution, I will learn from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Final Working Best Solution**
*Algorithm by PaulMcKenzie*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

std::string PaperPencilAlgorithm(std::string num1, std::string num2)
{
    std::reverse(num1.begin(), num1.end());
    std::reverse(num2.begin(), num2.end());
    if (num1.size() < num2.size())
        num1.resize(num2.size(), '0');
    else if (num2.size() < num1.size())
        num2.resize(num1.size(), '0');
    std::string result;

    int carry = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num1.size(); ++i)
    {
        int subtotal = (num1[i] - '0') + (num2[i] - '0') + carry;
        int subanswer = subtotal % 10;
        carry = subtotal / 10;
        result += (subanswer + '0');
    }
    if (carry == 1)
        result += '1';
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}

void Display()
{
    cout << "Paper and Pencil Algorithm Addition" << endl;
    string num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter num 1: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter num 2: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "Addition is : " + PaperPencilAlgorithm(num1, num2) << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");

    cout << "Want to add 2 more numbers? (Y/n)" << endl;
    char c;
    cin >> c;

    if (c == 'Y')
    {
        system("CLS");
        Display();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Display();
    return 0;
}
```